# How to select multiple values with the same ids and put them in one row, while maintaining the id to value connection?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `processknowledgeentry` table that has the following data:

```
pke_id   prc_id   knw_id
1        1        2
2        1        4
3        2        4
```

The column `knw_id` references another table called `knowledge`, which also has its own id column. **I want to be able to select all `knw_id` values with the same `prc_id`, and have them retain its nature as an id (so that it remains referenceable to the `knowledge` table)**.

Desired result:

```
prc_id   knw_ids
1        [2, 4]
```

My code is shown below. (It also selects a Process Name from another table called `process` by inner joining the `prc_id`s. That part works correctly at least.)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.prc_name, 
        (SELECT knw_id
            FROM processknowledgeentry
            GROUP BY knw_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    FROM processknowledgeentry pke
    INNER JOIN process p
    ON pke.prc_id=p.prc_id
    WHERE pke.prc_id = %s) as temp
```

I get the error: "*CardinalityViolation: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*", and I understand why the error exists, so I want to know how to work around it. I'm also not sure if my logic is correct.

Would appreciate any assistance, thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result you want to achieve based on the source data you’ve provided

Comment: I've edited my question. Please let me know if it is still unclear, thank you!

Comment: So how does concatenating the values into a comma-delimited string in any way satisfy *remains referenceable to the knowledge table*?

Comment: Hmm well, I'm thinking if it's an array, perhaps the ids may still be referenceable? Please let me know if this is logical or not.

Comment: you haven't suggested an array, your desired results suggest a string, as does your attempt to use *group_concat*, a string aggregate function of some other RDBMS products; Postgres has an *array_agg* function.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity of the question, I'm also just trying to figure things out. Thank you for bringing up the array_agg function, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need a `STRING_AGG()` function instead of `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which some other DBMS has, containing a string type parameter as the first argument along with HAVING clause which filters multiple `prc_id` values such as

```sql
SELECT p.prc_id, STRING_AGG(knw_id::TEXT,',') AS knw_ids
  FROM processknowledgeentry pke
  JOIN process p
    ON pke.prc_id = p.prc_id
-- WHERE pke.prc_id = %s
 GROUP BY p.prc_id
HAVING COUNT(pke.prc_id) > 1
```

Indeed this case, a WHERE clause won't be needed.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3027871616d90fa6994245de5c4e4721)</kbd>

Comment: you're welcome @deanne . Btw, if you need an array representation as shown by the last edit, then you can replace the current representation for `knw_ids` with `CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(knw_id::TEXT,','),']')` or `STRING_TO_ARRAY(STRING_AGG(knw_id::TEXT,','),',')` or                                      
 simply `ARRAY_AGG(knw_id)`